# Java Generics with Static Factory methods

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a `Variable` class that can represent either an `Integer` or `Double` value using generics.

Below is the code that I have tried. Because of erasure I use an `enum` to store the intended type of the `Variable` and then try and use this to initialise the value to the correct type.

```
public class Variable<T> {

    private enum Type {INTEGER, DOUBLE};
    private Type type;

    private T value;
    
    public static Variable<Integer> createAsInteger() {
        return new Variable<Integer>(Type.INTEGER);
    }

    public static Variable<Double> createAsDouble() {
        return new Variable<Double>(Type.DOUBLE);
    }
    
    private Variable(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
        
        if(type == Type.INTEGER) {
            value = new Integer(0);
        } else {
            value = new Double(0.0);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Variable.createAsInteger();
        Variable.createAsDouble();
    }

}
```

However when I compile it I get the following message...

```
error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to T
                    value = new Integer(0);
```

and likewise for the `Double`.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and if there is a way round this without having to write two separate classes, one for `Integer` and one for `Double`?

## Edit

Thanks for all your answers...based on them I now realise there are better ways of doing this. However I'm trying to get my head round why this approach isn't working so that I don't make the same mistake in the future.

When I define my class as `public class Variable<T extends Number>` as suggested, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Your architecture seems to defile the concept of generics.

The simplest way would be to have an upper bound in your type parameter:

```
class Variable<T extends Number> {...}
```

Then you can have a generic factory method creating a `Variable<X>` based on your required class:

```
static <X extends Number>Variable<X> create() {
    return new Variable<X>();
}
```

You can then invoke it as:

```
Variable.<Integer>create(); // returns an instance of `Variable<Integer>`
```

This will not limit to `Integer` and `Double`, but rather any `Number`.

If you have to, you can limit those choices by performing the following:

- Add a parameter to your `create` method: `create(Class<X> clazz)`
- Check the value of your `clazz` argument within the method's body:

  ```
  if (!clazz.equals(Integer.class) && !clazz.equals(Double.class)) {
      // TODO complain
  }
  ```

Otherwise, you can ensure you use a `private` constructor and provide `static createAs...` non-generic methods such as `createAsInteger` etc., that would return a `new Variable<Integer>` etc.

Comment: You don't actually need `Class<X> clazz` if you're not going to check the class variable. `static <X extends Number>Variable<X> create()` works.

Comment: @AndyTurner you're right of course. The `clazz` parameter is there only to allow fine-grained control of what the `Number` can or cannot be. I'll edit the answer though.

Comment: I haven't came across the two sets of diamond operators in a method statement before, i.e. `<X extends Number>Variable<X>`. Can you recommend any links where I can read more about these?

Comment: @soarjay this indicates a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). Its type argument is independent from the one in your generic class, hence the usefulness of having it as a static factory method.

Comment: Also inside the constructor I need to initialise the `value` to zero either by calling `new Integer(0)` or `new Double(0)` which is where I am encountering the difficulty!

Comment: @soarjay simply use a constructor taking `Number` as a parameter. It will then be wrapped to whatever numerical value type your `Variable` instance is holding.

Comment: @Mena I will definitely use that approach moving forward. However, can you explain why initialising the value in the constructor doesn't work when `<T extends Number>` is in the class declaration?

Comment: @soarjay the problem with bounded generic types is that the type is unknown. So if you don't know the type in advance, how can you initialize with a given numeric value, since you don't know which value is compatible? I.e. you can either have a constructor taking `T`, but you'll be unable to invoke a constructor with a value unless you're in a context where `T` is known, or you can have a constructor taking a `Number`, but then your instance field holding the value has to be a `Number` too, hence returning `T` in - say - a `get` method will not work with your instance field... etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `T` can be anything. What if `T` was for instance `String`, your code would amount to:

```
String value = new Integer(0);
```

---

You could lay out your factory methods like this:

```
public static Variable<Integer> createAsInteger() {
    return new Variable<>(new Integer(0), Type.INTEGER);
}
```

Where you have a constructor like:

```
private Variable(T value, Type type) {
    this.value = value;
    this.type = type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you are typizing a method inside a generic class. You can't define some  inside the T generic class.

By the way you are mistaking the design pattern.

You have to design a generic class for Variable, also the constructor must have T as argument type.

In an other class you implement the factory with the createInteger and the createDouble methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your class inherit from Numbers and use type checking to invoke appropriate method for Integer or Double.

```
public class Variable<T extends Number> {
     public static Variable<T extends Number> Variable<T> create(Variable<T> var){
               if (var instanceOf Integer){
                // Take appropriate action
               }
               else if (var instanceOf Double){
               // Take appropriate action
               }

     }
}
```

By this, there is no peculiar need of maintaining a separate enum for Types.